# IE9/IE 10 No Stylesheets

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, zurb-foundation

I've run into quite a roadblock. While I believe I got IE10 to work, IE 9 will not for the life of me display any of my custom styles. It's defaulting to Foundation. And that ridiculous off-canvas will not be hidden even after applying custom CSS.

I have to say I'm at a complete loss. The site is working flawlessly in all other browsers and it was working fine previously. Somewhere along the way something drastic was changed.

Site is pro-gard.com

And I'm so grateful for any help and insight.

Comment: Unfortunately cleaning the console didn't fix the IE9 issue.

Answer (score 0):

The site displays almost perfectly in Firefox, the navigation bar sits a pixel or two too high vertically. I can already see that you're using some CSS3 styles that may conflict with various versions of IE including your gradients / rounded corners.

Have you looked at [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)?

```
"Modernizr makes it easy for you to write conditional JavaScript and CSS to handle each situation, whether a browser supports a feature or not."
```

This may help resolve some of your non-compatible styles.

Also, you can check to see a full list of CSS compatibility with various IE versions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**Edit:** Based on your comment below, I've added the CSS limits for IE.

**Internet Explorer 6-9**

```
A sheet may contain up to 4095 rules
A sheet may @import up to 31 sheets
@import nesting supports up to 4 levels deep
```

**Internet Explorer 10**

```
A sheet may contain up to 65534 rules
A document may use up to 4095 stylesheets
@import nesting is limited to 4095 levels (due to the 4095 stylesheet limit)
```

Found this information: [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/14/internet-explorer-stylesheet-rule-selector-import-sheet-limit-maximum.aspx)

Comment: Yeah I'm working with foundation and I checked and it is referencing Modernizr so it seems it should be working. I'm wondering if IE can't call anymore stylesheets? The client has about 15 plugins on the site

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll look into those stylesheet rules. The most unusual thing is that my CSS is definitely being applied in IE8 but not IE9.

Comment: If you believe that IE8 is rendering your page correctly, you can try using "<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >" in your head section to have the browser attempt to render the page for IE8 even when in IE9. If it works, you could use a conditional statement to use that meta tag only when in IE9. This is probably not the best fix, FYI.

Comment: As a side note, I did see some JS / CSS errors in the web console.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I will look at the console. Unfortunately that code didn't fix it. I've been troubleshooting this one thing for hours. Can't imagine what's going on.

Comment: Cleaned the console of all errors with no luck to the IE stylesheets problem. Anyone else encountered this? Using Foundation 5 framework and Woocommerce

Comment: Looks like **http://www.pro-gard.com/wp-content/themes/progard/css/ie.css** does not exist. This is probably the cause of your error.

Comment: where should that exist? I didn't think foundation called it. should I create that stylesheet? What should I put in it?

Comment: It's in your source code, I believe it comes packaged with Wordpress considering it's in your themes folder. I know that Wordpress comes with IE-specific stylesheets for certain themes. Perhaps that file (assuming your theme was copied from a standard theme) is necessary for IE-specific styling.

Comment: It's unfortunately not the cause because a fellow developer is using the same theme and framework on a project that is working fine in IE9. Still not luck so far. Any insight so appreciated!